# Filtering with multiple criteria at the same time, not independent

Tags: r

I have two data sets, a and b.  They each have three columns:  ticker, date, and sector.

a is the database:  it contains ALL tickers, ALL dates, and the sector value for that ticker on that date.

b is a smaller subset where I have some tickers and some dates.  The sector column is all "0" for now, but I would like to get the sector value from dataset a.

I understand that I can write a for loop to iterate through each row, but I have millions of rows, so the runtime is not ideal.  I was trying to do this with vectorized code, but I get the warning that the longer object length is not a multiple of the shorter object length.  The code I was using is:

```
a %>% filter(a$ticker == b$ticker & a$date == b$date)
```

I tried replacing "==" with %in%, but the issue is that all of the tickers in a are in b, and all of the dates in a are in b (they are just not there in the same combinations).  Is there a way to get the filter() function to do both criteria at the same time when filtering?  ie, get the function to look at each row of dataset a and see if the ticker AND date are both inside b, then take that row if so?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `merge(a, b, by=c("ticker", "date")`

Comment: Or if you want to stick with `dplyr`, `inner_join`. Also, `,` and `&` are equivalent in `filter` FWIW.

Comment: That seems to have done it.  Thanks!
Just wondering, is there any difference between merge and inner_join?  ie, does one have additional functionality?

Comment: @user5811685 You don't have to specify `a$` in `filter` as you are piping `a` into filter.